# SqlConnectionStringBuilder Doesn't like Provider in it

Tags: c#, excel, ssis

`SqlConnectionStringBuilder` doesn't like `Provider` in it.

I fought with this for a while until I thought, try to use `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` with a connection string without the provider portion and it worked. I could not find any help regarding this problem, so I thought to post it. I will do it another way now that I know that it probably can't work.

Here is my connection string from the debugger:

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\\Src\\MyTest.xls;Extended Properties=\"EXCEL 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\";
```

This a valid connection string that was created in a SSIS package that runs from my Windows Forms app and works, so I know that it is correct.

Here is what I tried below with the results:

Attempt #1:

```
SqlConnectionStringBuilder sb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(cnExcel.ConnectionString);
```

This blows up with an error:

> 'new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(cnExcel.ConnectionString)' threw an exception of type 'System.ArgumentException'

Attempt #2: I also tried:

```
SqlConnectionStringBuilder sb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
sb.ConnectionString = cnExcel.ConnectionString;
```

And got the same exact error message when trying to set `sb.ConnectionString`.

There is probably an inner error message that is not being displayed in the watch window of the debugger or when it blows up.

But when I put the code into a try / catch the correct error is returned:

```
string excelConnectionName = "Excel Connection Manager";Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.ConnectionManager cnExcel = SSISFct.GetExcelConnection(pkg, excelConnectionName, "EXCEL");

if (cnExcel == null) 
    throw new Exception("[***]: Missing Excel Connection for Connection Name: " + excelConnectionName);

SqlConnectionStringBuilder sb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(); //new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(cnExcel.ConnectionString);

try
{
    sb.ConnectionString = cnExcel.ConnectionString;
    sb.DataSource = excelFileName;
    cnExcel.ConnectionString = sb.ConnectionString;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    int i = 1; //Junk code to set a break point at.
}
```

Now it returns in the debugger watch window:

```
ex  {"Keyword not supported: 'provider'."}  
System.Exception {System.ArgumentException}
```

So apparently I cannot use `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` to build a connection string for an Excel SSIS connection string.

Now the word "Duhh" comes to mind! I should not have been trying to use `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` for this purpose, since it is not a `SqlDataSource`. Bad move!

Maybe what I found can help someone else not to waste several hours trying to figure out! I hope so!

Comment: If you have an answer to your question, please post it below (as an answer).

Comment: Yes, in fact - `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` is **only** for connection string used by a `SqlConnection`, and that's SQL Server exclusively. But there's also a [`OleDbConnectionStringBuilder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnectionstringbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) - check it out!

Comment: Why do you use SqlConnectionStringBuilder? Why not simply using string withe the value you need?